# SQLCMD, BCP - stored procedures don't exist

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, bcp, sqlcmd

I'm trying to get a 'Hello World' going as a proof of concept using `sqlcmd` but I'm having a hard time:

[image]

Command:

```
 sqlcmd 'cmd.exe'
```

Error:

> Could not find stored procedure 'sqlcmd'.

I'm having a similar issue with BCP:

```
 bcp "SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3 FROM MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable"
```

> Could not find stored procedure 'bcp'.

This is a SQL Server 2014 machine. What's going on and how do I fix it?

Comment: `SQLCMD` and `bcp.exe` are both **external command-line tools** (not SQL Server stored procedures) - you need to open a command shell (`cmd.exe` or PowerShell) and run it there. On my machine with SQL Server 2014, they both live in the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn` directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @marc_s already pointed out, `SQLCMD` and `BCP` are external command-line tools. These cannot be called by starting with `bcp ...` or `sqlcmd ...` inside SQL Server.

If you want to run these commands from SQL Server, you need to form the command in a `VARCHAR` and execute the command through the use of the [`master.sys.xp_cmdshell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx) stored procedure. Calling this procedure will pass the command to the operating system to execute. Running this command will produce a resultset with each row being a line of the output of running this command.

Access to the `master.sys.xp_cmdshell` procedure first has to be enabled. This has to be done only once for your SQL Server installation. You can use this script to do that:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1 
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1 
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

After that you can use this stored procedure. I'll give an example based on the use of `BCP`. This will output all your table information (from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`) to `C:\Temp\information_schema.txt`.

```
DECLARE @stmt VARCHAR(8000);
SET @stmt='BCP "SELECT*FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES" QUERYOUT "C:\Temp\information_schema.txt" -c -T -S ' + @@SERVERNAME + ' -d ' + DB_NAME();
EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell @stmt;
```